# I want to budge this border to the left like in the pic

Tags: css, border

I want to budge this border to the left like in this image:

[image]

My code is like this:

```
div{
    border left: red 5px solid
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you want. So, first, you will need a class for your div, so that it doesn't affect every single div. You also need another `<div>` inside it for the text and the border. New code:

```
<div class="warn">
    <div class="inner-warn">This is important note</div>
</div>
```

Then, here comes the CSS. First, we should style the outer `<div>`. We will need padding, background color and you might want some border-radius. The padding should be around `7 pixels`. Your background color can be something like `#ddd`. It is what I saw in your picture. Finally, the border radius can be `5 pixels`, even though your image didn't contain any, I think it looks better. You can remove this. Our outer `<div>` code looks like this:

```
div.warn{
    padding: 7px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Now we have the inner `<div>`. It should contain a red left border (as you said in your code) and some left padding to not "touch" the border. Our code is like this:

```
div.inner-warn{
    border-left: red 5px solid;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Complete code:

```
<div class="warn">
    <div class="inner-warn">This is important note</div>
</div>
<style>
    div.warn{
        padding: 7px;
        background-color: #ddd;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    div.inner-warn{
        border-left: red 5px solid;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

Snippet:

```css
    div.warn{
        padding: 7px;
        background-color: #ddd;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    div.inner-warn{
        border-left: red 5px solid;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="warn">
    <div class="inner-warn">This is important note</div>
</div>
```

It looks like this:
[image: This is important note]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block{
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 16px;
}
.note{
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  padding-left: 16px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="note">This is an important note</div>
</div>
```